# Topology and taxi cab metric

Tags: general-topology

Let $A \subset \mathbb{R^k}$.Show that A is open if and only if it is open under the "taxi-cab metric" $d_{1}(x,y):=\sum_{j=1}^k|x_{j}-y{j}|. $

I was able to find that because $d_1(x,y)=\sum|x_j-y_j| $ if I take the square $d_1^2(x,y)=(\sum|x_j-y_j|)^2 $. If I take the square of the Euclidean distance I have $ d^2(x,y)=\sum|x_j-y_j|^2 $ and because distances are always $\geq0$ I have that $\sum |x_j-y_j|^2\leq (\sum|x_j-y_j|)^2$ and thus $d(x,y)\leq d_1(x,y)$. 
I don't know how to prove the other way i.e. prove that if A is open under the euclidean metric, then it is also open under the taxi cab-metric.

Comment: Try to find a constant such that $d_1(x,y) \leqslant c\cdot d(x,y)$ for all $x,y$. The Cauchy-Schwarz inequality is one way to obtain such a constant.

Comment: Is it possible to prove it without Cauchy-Schwarz?

Comment: Sure it's possible. You can get a constant elementarily by noting $\lvert x_i - y_i\rvert \leqslant d(x,y)$. But Cauchy-Schwarz gives you a sharp constant.

Answer (score 1):

Just expanding Daniel Fisher's comment, we have:
$$\sum_{j=1}^n |x_j|\leq \sqrt{n}\cdot\sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^{n}|x_j|^2}\tag{1}$$
in virtue of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, while
$$\left(\sum_{j=1}^{n}|x_j|\right)^2 \geq \sum_{j=1}^{n}|x_j|^2\tag{2}$$
is trivial. $(1)$ and $(2)$ give that a ball with respect to the $\ell_1$-norm contains a ball with respect to the $\ell_2$-norm that contains a smaller ball with respect to the $\ell_1$-norm and so on. So the two topologies induced by the $\ell_1$ and $\ell_2$ norm are equivalent.

Comment: I don't understand the first inequality. Why is that true?

Comment: I found this explanation: for vectors $ x = (x_1,x_2,··· ,x_k), y = (y_1,y_2,··· ,y_k) ∈ \mathbb {R}^n $,we choose * ∈ {1,2,···,n} so that $ max{|x_i−y_i|:1≤i≤n} = |x_*−y_*|$. The product $n^2 ·\sum |x_i − y_i|^2$ contains $ n^2 $ terms of the form $|x_∗−y_∗|^2 $and some extra non-negative terms. Hence,
$n^2 ·|x_∗ −y_∗|2 ≤ n^2 ·\sum|x_i −y_i|^2.$ Since $|x_∗−y_∗|^2 \leq n^2 \sum |x_i-y_i|^2$. If we take the square root we have: $|x_i-y_i| \leq n \sqrt{(\sum |x_i-y_i|^2)} $